# Using induction to prove Gram determinant is invariant under orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

let $\mathcal H$ be a complex Hilbertspace, and let  $g_1,...g_n\in \mathcal H$. let $G(g_1,...g_n)$ be Gram's determinant:

$\left|{\begin{array}{ccc}
\left(g_{1},g_{1}\right) & \dots & \left(g_{1},g_{n}\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\left(g_{n},g_{1}\right) & \dots & \left(g_{n},g_{n}\right)
\end{array}}\right|$

To show that orthogonalizing the vectors do not change the Gram determinant, we can show $G(g_1,...g_n)=G(g_1,h_2,g_3,...g_n)$ when $h_2=g_2+\alpha g_1$, such that $g_1\perp h_2$. Now I wanted to show this using induction and I have shown that in the case where the number of vectors is 2, the statement holds. Now by induction, we assume it holds for $2\leq n\leq k-1$ and shows it holds if we have $k$ vectors.  So I thought this would be an easy step since we can just use Laplace expansion and the smaller matrix should show up as a submatrix in the Laplace expansion, but that is in fact not the case. I looked at every possible row/column expansion and they don't work, so how do we prove the induction step?

Note: I know this can be proven without induction, but I am specifically asking for this because I want to know how to carry out the induction step.

Comment: If you think of the Gram matrix as a generalization of $A^T A$ where the vectors are the columns of $A$, then I would expect replacing $g_2$ by $g_2 + \alpha g_1$ to affect the Gram matrix as $G \mapsto E^T G E$ where $E$ is an elementary matrix with determinant 1.

Comment: So, maybe something like: if you add $\alpha$ times the first column to the second column, then you add $\alpha$ times the first row to the second row, then you transform the Gram matrix for $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ into the Gram matrix for $g_1, h_2, g_3, \ldots, g_n$.

Comment: I would start from the other end. When applying Gram-Schmid process the vector $h_n$ must be orthogonal to all the vectors $g_1,\ldots, g_{n-1}.$ So $h_n=g_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\alpha_k g_k.$ Replacing $g_n$ by $h_n$ in the last column corresponds to adding the linear combination of the first $n-1$ columns with coefficients $\bar{\alpha}_k$ to the last column. Similarly replacing $g_n$ with $h_n$ in the last row corresponds to similar operation for rows.  The new matrix will  have a block form with $G_{n-1}$ and $1\times 1$ matrix $\langle h_n,h_n\rangle $ Now you can perform an induction step.